# when trying to construct an Array of ints with a template for a Array class, Error: Why is the array type 'int [5]' is not assignable,

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor

When trying to build an array with a template, I get an error when
implementing a default constructor for the Array class template.

```
int main()
{
    Array<int,5> arrayOfFiveInts;
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
class Array
{
public:
   Array<T,SIZE>::Array()
   {
      elements = new T [SIZE];
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
         elements[i] = 0;
      } 
   }
private:
   T elements[SIZE];
};
```

I am expecting to see the array created when Main runs.

Comment: `elements` is already an array so there's no need to allocate more memory. And, unless this is homework, `std::array` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide whether you want to have the array in automatic or dynamic memory.

If you meant to have it in automatic memory, you have to remove the call to `new[]` in the constructor since `elements` is already allocated when it is declared.

If you meant to have it in dynamic memory, you have to change the declaration of `elements` to

```
T* elements;
```

If you do so, then you also need to make sure your class follows the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Add a destructor:

```
~Array()
{
    delete[] elements;
}
```

As well as implement (or delete) a copy/move constructor, and a copy/move assignment operator.

templates are header-only, you don't need to use the extra qualification:

```
Array<T,SIZE>::Array()
```

You have to define the class before the `main()` function in your example.

Check the correct format in 
[this Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M0N72bS90HrBkNGC).

Comment: Hello oblivion, the private data member is named
“elements” of type “array of SIZE elements of type ElemType”. Not really a pointer.

Comment: Here is what I was missing I think,  the default constructor for the Array class template should leave the underlying elements with their default value, not really initialize anything since you are right it's not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
elements = new T [SIZE];
```

`elements` is an array not a pointer, so trying to allocate some memory and assign to it doesn't make any sense.